# Bad routes for admin in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie in Laravel and wanna create Admin Login and Registration. I have user registration and it works properly.

My web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::view('/', 'index');

Route::name('user.')->group(function () {
   Route::view('/private', 'private')->middleware('auth')->name('private');

   Route::get('/login', function() {
       if (Auth::check()) {
           return redirect(route('user.private'));
       }
       return view('login');
   })->name('login');

   Route::post('/login', [\App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'login']);


    Route::get('/logout', function () {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('logout');

    Route::get('/registration', function() {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }
        return view('registration');
    })->name('registration');

    Route::post('/registration', [\App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController::class, 'save']);
});

Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::view('/adminPrivate', 'adminPrivate')->middleware('auth')->name('adminPrivate');
//    dd(Route::view('/adminPrivate', 'adminPrivate')->middleware('auth')->name('private'));

    Route::get('/adminLogin', function() {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {

            return redirect(route('admin.adminPrivate'));
        }
        return view('adminLogin');
    })->name('login');

    Route::post('/adminLogin', [\App\Http\Controllers\LoginAdminController::class, 'login']);


    Route::get('/adminLogout', function () {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('logout');

    Route::get('/adminRegistration', function() {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            return redirect(route('admin.adminPrivate'));
        }
        return view('adminRegistration');
    })->name('registration');

    Route::post('/adminRegistration', [\App\Http\Controllers\RegisterAdminController::class, 'save']);
});
```

My RegisterAdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RegisterAdminController extends Controller
{
    public function save(Request $request) {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            return redirect(route('admin.adminPrivate'));
        }

        $validateFields = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Admin::where('username', $validateFields['username'])->exists()) {
            return redirect(route('admin.registration'))->withErrors([
                'username' => 'Username already registered!'
            ]);
        }

        $admin = Admin::create($validateFields);
        if ($admin) {
            Auth::guard('admin')->login($admin);
            return redirect(route('admin.adminPrivate'));
        }
        return redirect(route('admin.login'))->withErrors([
            'formError' => 'Cannot save admin!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

My LoginAdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class LoginAdminController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request) {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            return Redirect::to(route('admin.adminPrivate'));
        }

        $formFields = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($formFields)) {
            return Redirect::to(route('admin.adminPrivate'));
        }

        return redirect(route('admin.login'))->withErrors([
            'username' => 'Can not authorize'
        ]);
    }
}
```

I don't understand how I can solve this problem. Need a help. I tried modify all names of my Routes, but this didn't help.

Comment: Take a look at the auth middleware. the logic does not belong in the route file

Comment: you could check out how others already did a authentication system and, to learn, try to "copy" them. an example is the [laravel breeze authentication starter kit](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze). you defo should check it out

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).